# Downloading same files twice under Network tab in browser (WASM file referred in JS file)

Tags: javascript, opencv, emscripten, wasm-bindgen

WASM file gets downloaded twice, Is there anyway we can avoid downloading same file more than once.

here ERT_Facial_Alignment_asm.js referring to ERT_Facial_Alignment_asm.wasm file, but wasm downloaded twice.

Please find attached file here.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a reason for this double download ?

Comment: i didnt find answer yet.

Comment: Hi, I found a fix, see the answer below, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be solved by setting correctly the header:

```
content-type=application/wasm
```

On your server hosting the wasm file.

When the content-type is not present, it will try to compile while downloading, then fail, then download again to compile offline.